# magento product category not applying, but applying after manual "save"

Tags: php, magento

I trying to create product programmatically, but it not showing at category page (at "frontend").
I use next code (yes, bad code, but it is one-time task)

```
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
...
$product->getResource()->save($product);
$product_id = $product->getId();

foreach (array($default_cat, $category_id) as $cat_id) {
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($cat_id,$product_id);
}
```

It succesfully create product, but when I open category page - it doesn't contain product. When I open product edit page and click "save" - product also added to category page...

What I can do?

UPD. Cache clearing and rendexing doesn't help... And, when I open product edit page - categories list are correct

UPD2. Reason was in qty/stock.

Comment: Related: [Programatic category update not taking effect until Save in Admin](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6729/programatic-category-update-not-taking-effect-until-save-in-admin)

Comment: Not working for me... Code at [link](http://pastebin.com/4dFxqHTq), it's `add_product` function

Comment: have you assign website & inventory stock?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149014/magento-not-displaing-stored-articles

Answer (score 0):

`$product->setCategoryIds(1,2,3,4,5)->save()`
?

Comment: Code snippets are not answers.  Please edit your answer and explain what this code is, how it works, and how it answers the question.

Comment: Also used, but have same effect. Now trying first comments